# Split and Count a Python String

Tags: python, arcpy

So I have a string:

```
stringvar = "one;two;three;four"
```

I want to turn that into:

```
stringcount = 4
string1 = "one"
string2 = "two"
string3 = "three"
string4 = "four"
```

Sometimes there will be more sometimes less and of course the values could be whatever. I am looking to split a string at the ';' into separate variables and then have another variable that gives the number of variables.

thanks

Comment: Did you google for Python string split? [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: just split it into a `list`, not four local variables.  [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: Is this supposed to be `"stringvar = one;two;three;four"` or `stringvar = "one;two;three;four"` ?

Comment: i forgot to add quotations before, I have added them now

Comment: @thefourtheye that's pretty broad -- you can find every implementation detail worth knowing in the docs, so nearly EVERY question on SO is "searching the docs for the OP." I agree this is very elementary, however. It is a teachable moment, which gives it value. (OP wants to put data in his variable names. Whip him until he succumbs to the glory of containers!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing something genuinely wrong and evil in python.

Comment: @zmo That much, at least, I agree with! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[NEVER DO THIS.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Okay, now that we have that out of the way, here's how you do that.

```
stringvar = "one;two;three;four"

lst = stringvar.split(";")
stringcount = len(lst)

for idx, value in enumerate(lst):
    globals()["string"+str(idx+1)] = value
    # This is the ugliest code I've ever had to write
    # please never do this. Please never ever do this.
```

`globals()` returns a dictionary containing every variable in the global scope with the variable name as a string for keys and the value as, well, values.

For instance:

```
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> baz = "eggs"
>>> spam = "have fun stormin' the castle"
>>> globals()
{'baz': 'eggs', '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'foo': 'bar', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, 'spam': "have fun stormin' the castle", '__name__': '__main__'}
```

You can reference this dictionary to add new variables by string name (`globals()['a'] = 'b'` sets variable `a` equal to `"b"`), but this is generally a terrible thing to do. Think of how you could possibly USE this data! You'd have to bind the new variable name to ANOTHER variable, then use that inside `globals()[NEW_VARIABLE]` every time! Let's use a `list` instead, shall we?

Comment: thanks for the help and lesson. looks like i will be frequenting this place often and getting chewed out for my questions along the way i guess haha

Comment: @J-roc this is one of the first mistakes I made in an actual project, so I'm a little more vehement about it than most. I had to build a script that would poll about 100 terminals and check the file size of ~20 files on each. As a novice, I did just what I'm advising you not to and used `globals()[filename].append((terminalID,size))`. It ended up being a massive bit of spaghetti code that I spent several weeks hacking back into shape a few months later. It was ugly.

Comment: @J-roc for reference, what I SHOULD have done is put it in a `dict`, either referenced by `terminalID` or by `filename`. `{terminalID: {filename: size, filename2: size}, terminalID_2: {...}}` is what I ended up doing to fix it.

Comment: Oh, gosh this is great. I had no idea you could do this. I can't imagine I'd ever want to but I'm impressed.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringvar_list= stringvar.split(';')
string_count = len(stringvar_list)
```

`stringvar_list` would then have the individual strings

Answer (score 2):

```
newstr = stringvar.split(";")
n = len(newstr)
print "stringcount = " + str(n)
for i in range(n):
    print "string"+i+"="+str(newstr[i])
```

Comment: `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: sorry for that use str(newstr[i])

Comment: That's not the error, it's still gonna throw the same exception. You can't do `print str+int+str+str` any more than you could do `print str+int+str+int` :)

Comment: Not to mention this doesn't give variables the way OP asked. It's not a good thing to do, but it's at least worth mentioning that you're tricking the user into thinking the variables are created when they're really not

Answer (score 1):

You should use `split` method

```
s = 'stringvar = "one;two,three;four"'
stringvar = s.split('=')[-1].strip()
L=stringvar.split(';')
stringcount=len(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringvar = "one;two,three;four"
l = stringvar.split(';')
stringcount, string1, string2, string3, string4 = len(l), l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]
```

Comment: As per OP: "Sometimes there will be more sometimes less and of course the values could be whatever"